# How to format selected text in monospace in Apple Notes app?

Tags: notes.app, formatting

When I select a text and hit Command+Shift M, It format the whole line instead of the selected text.

Example:

*This is a code*

expected:
*This is a `code`*

What I have:
*`This is a code`*

Comment: Happens to me too, I think that is expected behavior. EG it's working how Apple **wants** it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can't change it. MonoSpace falls under ***Paragraph Style*** in Notes and it implies for whole sentence or paragraph.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are changing paragraph style. If I understood correctly you probably look for ways to change font instead. After you have selected text hit ⌘ + T (will take to Fonts -> Show Fonts) select desired font and it will be applied to selected text only.

Comment: ⌘ + T is very close to what I want but I want just a monospaced font. Of course I can chose a monospaced font from that list that pop up but if you sync to let's say an iOS it shows a completely different font.

Comment: For syncing between Notes in macOS and iOS following approach could be used: format paragraph as Monospace with ⌘ + ↑ + M; after that choose and change font of part(s) needed to be changed to non-monospace.